# Allow plus (+) Javascript keyCode

Tags: javascript

I need to allow user to add plus (+) in mobile field. I have this javascript functions. How can I customize this code to allow plus (+) ?

```
function validateNumber(event) {
    var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    if (event.keyCode != 43 || event.keyCode === 8 || event.keyCode === 46) {
        return true;
    } else if (event.keyCode == 43) {
        return true;
    } else if (key < 48 || key > 57) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the desktop Chrome browser it already returns `true` for the `+` key on the number pad.  As well as using `CTRL` + `=`.

Answer (score 3):

The value of `event.key` for a plus symbol is `'+'` and the value of `event.which` for a plus symbol is `187. You can use those facts to add an appropriate condition to you validation logic.

By the way, here is a fantastic ressource on key codes: https://keycode.info/

By the way, both the [`event.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) and [`event.keycode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#:%7E:text=The%20deprecated%20KeyboardEvent.,identified%2C%20this%20value%20is%200%20.) properties are deprecated and so I would recommend using [`event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead for identifying which key is pressed.

Comment: Good suggestion, but still, filtering out keys is not the best solution for this problem. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64091395/3723993

Answer (score 1):

Both `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also makes the code easier to understand, as `e.key === '+'` for the <kbd>+</kbd> key. Just keep in mind some old browsers used non-standard codes for some keys, so, for example, left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE it's just `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead.

If you need to check KeyboardEvent's properties values such as `e.key`, `e.code`, `e.which` or `e.keyCode` you can use https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon!

[image: Key.js \ JavaScript KeyboardEvent's key codes & key identifiers]

**Disclaimer: I'm the author.**

Anyway, you should not listen for keyboard events (`keydown` / `keypress` / `keyup`) to filter out certain characters, as the value of the input can also be updated by pasting or dropping text into it and there are many exceptions you should not prevent, such as arrows, delete, escape, shortcuts such as select all, copy, paste... so trying to come up with an exhaustive list of the ones that should be allowed is probably not a good idea.

Moreover, that won't work on mobile, where most keys emit the same values `e.key = 'Unidentified'`, `e.which== 229` and `e.keyCode = 229`.

Instead, just listen for the `input` event and update the input value removing all invalid characters while preserving the cursor's position:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');

input.oninput = (e) => {  
  const cursorPosition = input.selectionStart - 1;
  const hasInvalidCharacters = input.value.match(/[^0-9+]/);

  if (!hasInvalidCharacters) return;
  
  // Replace all non-digits:
  input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, '');
  
  // Keep cursor position:
  input.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
};
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Digits and + only" />
```

Here you can see a similar answer and example for a slightly more complex behaviour to allow only numbers with one single decimal separator: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084513/3723993

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
function isNumberKey(evt)
{
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode != 43 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I am getting error - This field is required.Should be a valid integr value

Comment: Both `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are deprecated, so `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead.